# Discord py 2.0 interaction option

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Discord 2.0 Py**\

```
@bot.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(amount="Please give amount")
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"You clean {amount} message", ephemeral=True)
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Hello this is my code. All good, but i want do this command an option. So i mean command can non required ? Can user give a empty argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the option not required by setting a default value for it, and the library will make it optional for you.

```py
# set the default value for the "amount" argument to 1; if the user doesn't input the option, the argument will be 1.
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int = 1):
```

You can look at the official example [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py#L68-L75).

Comment: Thank you it worked ! Can i ask another question ? So how we can do this method in str ? Like **question: str**